# How to hide Login and Register link to other pages in Angular

Tags: html, angular

In App.component.ts I have redirected the router link to home, where I want to hide Login and Register link. I know lot of people will answer authGuard, I am new to angular. Just want to know how to hide some link or feature on diferent diferent pages on router base I think I can do it in ngIf and router link but where to write. Flow is after clicking on login or register want to hide the link
Can anyone please help?

```
    <a [routerLink]="['/login']"  class="btn btn-link">Login</a>
<a [routerLink]="['/registration']"  class="btn btn-link">Register</a>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a logged in flag on a shared service.

Create a serviceCalled LoggedIn

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoggedInService {
  loggedIn$ = new BehaviorSubject(false);
}
```

Inject the service where you log in and call next on the BehaviorSubject when you log in

```
this.loggedInService.loggedIn$.next(true);
```

and on the component with the menu use it to hide the login button

```
loggedIn$ = this.loggedInService.loggedIn$;
```

and in the template

```
<a [routerLink]="['/login']"  class="btn btn-link" *ngIf="loggedIn$ | async">Login</a>
```

Comment: I have removed the un necessary code. Do not want to hide nav bar or something. Simple requirement without authgurad service want to hide login and register button in my home page. Flow is after clicking itself login I have redirect to login component here itself want to hide login and register button.

Comment: Use a shared service with a behavior subject.